# Have shape and circle class, and point class. Segmentation fault when creating circle with point class as one parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, segmentation-fault, abstract-class

Here is my Shape.h. Ignore all the code that is commented out. That is from a version that I believe was incorrect but I left it in there in case I was wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Point.h"


using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public:

        Shape() {}
        virtual ~Shape() {}

        /*
        virtual float calcArea(const Shape& s) const = 0;
        virtual float calcCircum(const Shape& s) const = 0;
        virtual string calcBox(const Shape& s) const = 0;
        virtual void display(const Shape& s) const = 0;
        */

            virtual float calcArea() const = 0;
            virtual float calcCircum() const = 0;
            virtual string calcBox() const = 0;
            virtual void display() const = 0;

};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public:
    int radius;
    int pointX;
    int pointY;
    Point *middlePoint;
    float PI;

    Circle() : Shape() {
        middlePoint = new Point(0,0);
        radius = 0;
    }
    ~Circle() {}

    Circle(int rad, Point& p) : Shape() {
        PI = 3.141592;
        *middlePoint = p;
        pointX = p.getX();
        pointY = p.getY();
        radius = rad;
    }

    // float calcArea(const Circle& s) const {
    float calcArea() const {
        float tempArea;
    //  tempArea = PI * s.radius * s.radius;
    tempArea = PI * radius * radius;
        return tempArea;
        }

    // float calcCircum(const Circle& s) const {
    float calcCircum() const {
    //  int diameter = 2 * s.radius;
    int diameter = 2 * radius;
        float tempCircum;
        tempCircum = PI * diameter;
        return tempCircum;

    }

    // string calcBox(const Circle& s) const {
    string calcBox() const {
//      int x = s.pointX;
//      int y = s.pointY;
//      int r = s.radius;
    int x = pointX;
    int y = pointY;
    int r = radius;
        int tlX = x - r;
        int tlY = y + r;

        int blX = x - r;
        int blY = y - r;

        int trX = x + r;
        int trY = y + r;

        int brX = x + r;
        int brY = y - r;

        Point *topLeft = new Point(tlX,tlY);
        Point *bottomLeft = new Point(blX,blY);
        Point *topRight = new Point(trX,trY);
        Point *bottomRight = new Point(brX,brY);

        stringstream output;
        string tempOut;
        output << *topLeft << *bottomLeft << *topRight << *bottomRight;
        tempOut = output.str();
        return tempOut;

    }

    // void display(const Circle& s) const {
    void display() const {
        cout << "Class Name: Circle" << endl;
//      float tmpArea = calcArea(s);
    float tmpArea = calcArea();
        cout << "Area = " << tmpArea << endl;
//      cout << "Radius = " << s.radius << endl;
    cout << "Radius = " << radius << endl;
//      float tmpCircum = calcCircum(s);
    float tmpCircum = calcCircum();
        cout << "Circumference = " << tmpCircum << endl;
        cout <<"Middle Point = " << middlePoint;
//      string bbox = calcBox(s);
    string bbox = calcBox();
        cout <<"Bounding Box Points = " << bbox;
    }
};
```

---

Here is my TMA4Question1.cpp code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Shape.h"

int main() {

    Point *circlePoint = new Point(10,-5);

    Circle *mainCircle = new Circle(23,*circlePoint);
}
```

Ok. Yes this is a homework assignment for University. I'm not looking just for the answer, I would like to know why this program gives me a segmentation fault and how to correct it.

I know the error is in the Circle code, where I pass a pointer to the circlePOint in the constructor for the Circle class. I dont know why it generates a seg fault. I hope someone can provide some insight. Thanks.

Sorry if the code is messy. Had a hard time pasting it into here properly with 4 spaces and all that.

Comment: I think you meant to do `new Circle(23, circlePoint);`

Answer (score 0):

`middlePoint` is not allocated in your second `Circle` constructor.  You are assigning a value to it before giving it some memory.  As an aside, I don't see why anything there needs to be a pointer.

Comment: Yes - you should do middlePoint = new Point(p) instead of *middlepoint = p

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use pointers to Points inside your classes at all? You only generate memory leaks this way and (without your own copy operations) cause problems with as the midpoints could be shared by different circles.

PS: And it's not needed to have a PI value (even as non-const) in every circle - just use the constant from (afair) cmath for it.